# How can i trust state in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in react, `setState()` is async, and may buffer calls to change state. I get that. And how you may use `setState((state) => {})` like this with an optional callback if you depend on the state in some way for computing the new state.

But lets say i don't want to simply update state, but just be sure of what it actually contains at a certain point in time? Let's do an example:

I have a text field. When someone edits that field it sets state with `setState({ hasChanged: true })`. Very well. On a `onClick` callback (somewhere else) i wanna check if text field is "changed" and save the the textual content of it before moving on. But the thing is i can never really be sure `state.hasChanged` actually is in sync with reality. Unlike the callback in `setState((state) => {})`, i'm on my own here.

So do i create a "shadow state" (or, at least a state variable decoupled from the react state) and keep it updated just for situations such as this? Seems a little cumbersome, and i suspect this is not how you are supposed to do it, hence this question.

EDIT for clarification: i only wish to "check" state and be sure of it's content (because i'm my case, i will do a save-to-disk depending on it). I'm actually not gonna update the state. If that was the case, setState with callback would probably be the right choice..

Comment: I am in that case I would add an attribute in state like `previousStateTextFiled' and compare with current. If not-> currentState is a previos)

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly theoretical question and this will most likely never be a problem for scenario's like the example you gave.

Anyways, you can pass a callback to setState as a second parameter, it will get called as soon as your state has been changed.

Comment: Yes i suppose it's a bit theoretical, but i'm designing a react app right now, and i save that text field content to disk (if it's changed) before filling it with new content. Which is the reason i wanna be *real* sure i don't miss saving it just because state isn't in sync with reality.So i suppose i could use setState with callback as a crutch (even tho i'm actually no updating state, rather just performing an action because of it (save to disk)

Answer (score 0):

That's why React has a lifecycle in which you can listen via methods such as `componentWillUpdate`, `componentDidUpdate`, etc (you can check the full list [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_component_life_cycle.htm)). 
Following your example, when a text field changes, the state `value` is updated, and you can "intercept" this change within the methods `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` like this:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };

    this._handleOnChange = this._handleOnChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextState.value !== this.state.value) {
      console.log('value will update');
    }
  }
  
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.value !== this.state.value) {
      console.log('value did update', this.state.value);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type='text' autoFocus onChange={this._handleOnChange} ref='text'/>
      </form>
    );
  }
  
  _handleOnChange() {
    this.setState({
      value: this.refs.text.value
    });
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("main"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

You can find more info about state and lifecycles in the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Will `componentWillUpdate` also run delayed (batch changes and run *just* before render) or immediately just after state change?

Comment: It runs after `shouldComponentUpdate`.  http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Comment: While i *really* appreciate the effort,  i fail to see how that solves my dilemma. Maybe i'm just not understanding you. And also, maybe my problem is architectural to begin with. I just tried out, `shouldComponentUpdate` and it does indeed do batched changes, so i might miss the particular point in time when i need to inspect and act on *that* particular state. But if i were depending on some **final** state, then yes it could probably be a solution somehow. Maybe i could introduce state variables i could trust in a **final** form and act on them. in any case, thanks for the insight and ideas

Answer (score 0):

I really think this is a very difficult case to happen. We know that `setState` only takes a few fractions of a second to execute, and in a real scenario, when the button is clicked, the state has already changed.

In order to be able to fully trust that `react` is doing a good job, I can think of some ideas:

- You can disable the button when `this.state.hasChanged` is false. So you should always wait for the next `render` to check the status of`hasChanged` and to enable it.
- Use a new key inside `state` that says`lastAction` and help of `componentDidUpdate` to have rules such as:

  `if (this.state.lastAction === "myLastAction")`

Comment: it's indeed unlikely to happen in this case. However, it *is* a corner case, and could possibly be a very hard bug to trace. And besides (maybe i'm nitpicking here) i wanna "do it right" from the start and not depend on "it'll work 999 times out of 1000". And thanks for the tips!